# HTACCESS: Remove extension, return 404 if original with extension, but make code if has query string

Tags: .htaccess

**.htaccess**

```
# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

This works fine, but how to modify the code so that a language switch based on [this code](https://daveismyname.blog/how-to-create-a-language-changer-with-php) works?

**Currently it does the following:**

```
localhost/index = OK
localhost/index.php = OK (404 error)
```

but when you press the button

```
<a href="?la=en">EN</a>
```

it will change the address as follows

```
localhost/index => localhost/index.php?la=en = FAIL (404 page)
```

which throws 404 error as well. Is it possible to prevent it? Would it just prevent the .php from being added before the query string? I want the language switch to work as well, is it possible? Any ideas?

**Language switch:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET['la']){
    $_SESSION['la'] = $_GET['la'];
    header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}

switch($_SESSION['la']){
     case "eng":
        require('lang/eng.php');
    break;
    case "fre":
        require('lang/fre.php');
    break;
    case "ger":
        require('lang/ger.php');
    break;
    default:
        require('lang/eng.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title><?php echo $lang['index-title'];?></title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="langSelect">
        <a href="index.php?la=eng"><img src="flags/eng.png" alt="<?=$lang['lang-eng'];?>" title="<?=$lang['lang-eng'];?>" /></a>
        <a href="index.php?la=fre"><img src="flags/fra.png" alt="<?=$lang['lang-fre'];?>" title="<?=$lang['lang-fre'];?>" /></a>
        <a href="index.php?la=ger"><img src="flags/ger.png" alt="<?=$lang['lang-ger'];?>" title="<?=$lang['lang-ger'];?>" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="cont">
        <p><?=$lang['index-welcome'];?></p>
        <p><?=$lang['index-text-1'];?></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**SOLVED!**

Replace:

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

With:

```
header('Location:'. str_replace(".php", "", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Comment: you can do : `<a href="/index?la=en">EN</a>`

Comment: This does not work, localhost/index?la=en => localhost/index.php and I really do not know why it's happening.

Comment: I have test with your .htaccess. `http://localhost/test/index?s=a` is not going to `localhost/index.php?s=a`

Comment: did you test it along with the language switch? When I type it in an address, it does not go to .php. But I need it or change it with that language switch.

Comment: I tested it with GET params. can you try with `http://localhost/test/index?s=a` and see if it is working?

Comment: When I write to the address index?la=en, the page loads and the parameter is visible in the address. But if I press a button that has href="index?la=en" it redirects to index.php and throws a 404 error. I think the language switch will need to be changed or a new one will need to be written, but I do not know the advice.

Comment: can you change ` href="index?la=en" ` to ` href="/index?la=en" ` and let me know what is happening?

Comment: absolutely nothing.It still redirects to index.php. I tried href="?la=en", href="index?la=en", href="/index?la=en" even retrieve name files via php but nothing. Everything goes all the way to index.php

Comment: I have updated my question. Now you can see the language switch that you probably need to edit but I do not know how. A full example: https://daveismyname.blog/how-to-create-a-language-changer-with-php

Comment: problem is at `header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at : `header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

> The $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is a super global variable that returns the
>   filename of the currently executing script.

Change it to:

```
header('Location:'. str_replace(".php", "", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

which remove the extension from the string.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Switching language takes about a second longer than ever, but it works !!!! Thanks, i love you.

Comment: Glad it helped. you can accept/upvote the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Can I ask why switching language takes just a little longer with this?

Comment: previously, it executed till header() and threw an error.
Now, The time_taken = time_taken to redirect + load and render the entire index.php again including your require scripts.

Comment: It does not matter at that second, I use preloader. Thanks for your help one more time!